# Gmail aligned right to left

Tags: gmail

I pressed some shortcut probably and the Gmail aligned right to left.

Not text, but whole page itself.[image]

Any ideas how change it back to normal view?

Comment: This used to be available as a labs feature - [but was removed years ago](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/ZgQ2_lAtIB4)!? In the current Gmail you would seem to have to change the language (Arabic, Hebrew, or Urdu) to get the labels on the right?! Reference: https://gmail.googleblog.com/2009/07/labels-drag-and-drop-hiding-and-more.html Do you have the additional keyboard shortcuts turned on? Presumably the "cog" menu button is now way over on the left? Or is it just shifted across a bit?

Comment: Is it just Gmail? Does it happen in any other Google apps? Any other websites?

Comment: After checking the great suggestions from w3dk & AI E. , I would recommend checking your Google account settings mainly because I can see the profile pic, bell, and apps launcher are also on the left. Click your profile pic, then My Account. Next select "Language & Input Tools" and check these settings. I can tell your Gmail language isn't English because the Trash label is referred to as Bin.

Answer (score -1):

This will realign it on Windows/Linux:
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>

And on Mac OS

<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>

Comment: Why? What's that keyboard shortcut for? (For what it's worth, it doesn't work for me.)

Comment: Try `cmd` if you're on a Mac. Some languages are right aligned and written right-to-left. This shortcut toggles between left/right aligned languages.